# Updating sql data through PHP

Tags: php

Good day!

I am having a problem in showing the data that I need to Update.

For example: I have a field - NAME. And user input "John Travolta" on it and enter to save it in SQL. Then to update it, he will click the update and a textbox will appear with the name "John Travolta" with it.

The problem is I am only getting "John" and the "Travolta" does not appear on the text box.

My code is as follows:

```
<input name="event" type="text" id="event" size="69" value=<?php print stripslashes($row_array['event'])?>>
```

What can i do in order for the whole name to appear in the textbox?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: How does the name look in the database?

Comment: Did you check the database to make sure that the data is correct? Could you provide the code on how you're inserting/getting your data?

Comment: Also check your database NAME field length.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to put quotes before and after the PHP line so HTML can parse it as a string.
otherwise you will end with `value=John Travolta` when you want `value="John Travolta"`

Answer (score 1):

Use that code:

```
<input name="event" type="text" id="event" size="69" value="<?php print stripslashes($row_array['event']);?>">
```